# how to add a delay between drawing paths of an svg file in android

Tags: android, svg

My SVG file is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="500" width="500"
                                                                                   viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">

 <path id="p" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" d="M100,100 C 200,100 200,250 100,250 "/>


<path id="b" d="M 100 250 l 100 0 " stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke="blue" />



 <path id="c" d=" M 200 100 l 0 300" stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke="blue" />



  <path id="e" d=" M 250 100 l 0 300 " stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>


 <path id="f" d="M 50 100 l 350 0" stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>

</svg>
```

My SvgUtils.java is:

```
/**
 * Util class to init and get paths from svg.
 */

public class SvgUtils {
    /**
     * It is for logging purposes.
     */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "SVGUtils";
    /**
     * All the paths with their attributes from the svg.
     */
    private final List<SvgPath> mPaths = new ArrayList<SvgPath>();
    /**
     * The paint provided from the view.
     */
    private final Paint mSourcePaint;
    /**
     * The init svg.
     */
    private SVG mSvg;

    /**
     * Init the SVGUtils with a paint for coloring.
     *
     * @param sourcePaint - the paint for the coloring.
     */
    public SvgUtils(final Paint sourcePaint) {
        mSourcePaint = sourcePaint;
    }

    /**
     * Loading the svg from the resources.
     *
     * @param context     Context object to get the resources.
     * @param svgResource int resource id of the svg.
     */
    public void load(Context context, int svgResource) {
        if (mSvg != null) return;
        try {
            mSvg = SVG.getFromResource(context, svgResource);
            mSvg.setDocumentPreserveAspectRatio(PreserveAspectRatio.UNSCALED);
        } catch (SVGParseException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not load specified SVG resource", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draw the svg to the canvas.
     *
     * @param canvas The canvas to be drawn.
     * @param width  The width of the canvas.
     * @param height The height of the canvas.
     */
    public void drawSvgAfter(final Canvas canvas, final int width, final int height) {
        final float strokeWidth = mSourcePaint.getStrokeWidth();
        rescaleCanvas(width, height, strokeWidth, canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Render the svg to canvas and catch all the paths while rendering.
     *
     * @param width  - the width to scale down the view to,
     * @param height - the height to scale down the view to,
     * @return All the paths from the svg.
     */
    public List<SvgPath> getPathsForViewport(final int width, final int height) {
        final float strokeWidth = mSourcePaint.getStrokeWidth();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
            private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

            @Override
            public int getWidth() {
                return width;
            }

            @Override
            public int getHeight() {
                return height;
            }

            @Override
            public void drawPath(Path path, Paint paint) {
                Path dst = new Path();

                //noinspection deprecation
                getMatrix(mMatrix);
                path.transform(mMatrix, dst);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
                mPaths.add(new SvgPath(dst, paint));
            }
        };

        rescaleCanvas(width, height, strokeWidth, canvas);

        return mPaths;
    }

    /**
     * Rescale the canvas with specific width and height.
     *
     * @param width       The width of the canvas.
     * @param height      The height of the canvas.
     * @param strokeWidth Width of the path to add to scaling.
     * @param canvas      The canvas to be drawn.
     */
    private void rescaleCanvas(int width, int height, float strokeWidth, Canvas canvas) {
        final RectF viewBox = mSvg.getDocumentViewBox();

        final float scale = Math.min(width
                        / (viewBox.width() + strokeWidth),
                height / (viewBox.height() + strokeWidth));

        canvas.translate((width - viewBox.width() * scale) / 2.0f,
                (height - viewBox.height() * scale) / 2.0f);
        canvas.scale(scale, scale);

        mSvg.renderToCanvas(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Path with bounds for scalling , length and paint.
     */
    public static class SvgPath {
        /**
         * Region of the path.
         */
        private static final Region REGION = new Region();
        /**
         * This is done for clipping the bounds of the path.
         */
        private static final Region MAX_CLIP =
                new Region(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE,
                        Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        /**
         * The path itself.
         */
        final Path path;
        /**
         * The paint to be drawn later.
         */
        final Paint paint;
        /**
         * The length of the path.
         */
        final float length;
        /**
         * The bounds of the path.
         */
        final Rect bounds;
        /**
         * The measure of the path, we can use it later to get segment of it.
         */
        final PathMeasure measure;

        /**
         * Constructor to add the path and the paint.
         *
         * @param path  The path that comes from the rendered svg.
         * @param paint The result paint.
         */
        SvgPath(Path path, Paint paint) {
            this.path = path;
            this.paint = paint;

            measure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
            this.length = measure.getLength();

            REGION.setPath(path, MAX_CLIP);
            bounds = REGION.getBounds();
        }
    }
}
```

My PathView is:

```
/**
 * PathView is an View that animate paths.
 */
public class PathView extends View {

   static Bitmap bitmap=null;
    Canvas canvas;
    /**
     * Logging tag.
     */
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "PathView";
    /**
     * The paint for the path.
     */
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    /**
     * Utils to catch the paths from the svg.
     */
    private final SvgUtils svgUtils = new SvgUtils(paint);
    /**
     * All the paths provided to the view. Both from Path and Svg.
     */
    private List<SvgUtils.SvgPath> paths = new ArrayList<SvgUtils.SvgPath>(0);
    /**
     * This is a lock before the view is redrawn
     * or resided it must be synchronized with this object.
     */
    private final Object mSvgLock = new Object();
    /**
     * Thread for working with the object above.
     */
    private Thread mLoader;

    /**
     * The svg image from the raw directory.
     */
    private int svgResourceId;
    /**
     * Object that build the animation for the path.
     */
    private AnimatorBuilder animatorBuilder;
    /**
     * The progress of the drawing.
     */
    private float progress = 0f;

    /**
     * If the used colors are from the svg or from the set color.
     */
    private boolean naturalColors;
    /**
     * If the view is filled with its natural colors after path drawing.
     */
    private boolean fillAfter;
    /**
     * The width of the view.
     */
    private int width;
    /**
     * The height of the view.
     */
    private int height;


  public void  saveBitmap(){
     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(),getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      //Bind a canvas to it
     canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }


    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param context The Context of the application.
     */
    public PathView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param context The Context of the application.
     * @param attrs   attributes provided from the resources.
     */
    public PathView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param context  The Context of the application.
     * @param attrs    attributes provided from the resources.
     * @param defStyle Default style.
     */
    public PathView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        getFromAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Get all the fields from the attributes .
     *
     * @param context The Context of the application.
     * @param attrs   attributes provided from the resources.
     */
    private void getFromAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PathView);
        try {
            if (a != null) {
                paint.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.PathView_pathColor, 0xff00ff00));
                paint.setStrokeWidth(a.getFloat(R.styleable.PathView_pathWidth, 8.0f));
                svgResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PathView_svg, 0);
            }
        } finally {
            if (a != null) {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set paths to be drawn and animated.
     *
     * @param paths - Paths that can be drawn.
     */
    public void setPaths(final List<Path> paths) {
        for (Path path : paths) {
            this.paths.add(new SvgUtils.SvgPath(path, paint));
        }
        synchronized (mSvgLock) {
            updatePathsPhaseLocked();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set path to be drawn and animated.
     *
     * @param path - Paths that can be drawn.
     */
    public void setPath(final Path path) {
        paths.add(new SvgUtils.SvgPath(path, paint));
        synchronized (mSvgLock) {
            updatePathsPhaseLocked();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Animate this property. It is the percentage of the path that is drawn.
     * It must be [0,1].
     *
     * @param percentage float the percentage of the path.
     */
    public void setPercentage(float percentage) {
        if (percentage < 0.0f || percentage > 1.0f) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("setPercentage not between 0.0f and 1.0f");
        }
        progress = percentage;
        synchronized (mSvgLock) {
            updatePathsPhaseLocked();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * This refreshes the paths before draw and resize.
     */
    private void updatePathsPhaseLocked() {
        final int count = paths.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            SvgUtils.SvgPath svgPath = paths.get(i);
            svgPath.path.reset();
            svgPath.measure.getSegment(0.0f, svgPath.length * progress, svgPath.path, true);
            // Required only for Android 4.4 and earlier
            svgPath.path.rLineTo(0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
int count=paths.size();
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
final Canvas canvasmy=canvas;
       // synchronized (mSvgLock) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
            final int count = paths.size();
            Log.i("Count in onDraw",String.valueOf(count));
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final SvgUtils.SvgPath svgPath = paths.get(i);

                final Path path = svgPath.path;
                final Paint paint1 = naturalColors ? svgPath.paint : paint;


                        canvas.drawPath(path, paint1);    // Do something after 5s = 5000ms


            }
           // fillAfter(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        super.onDraw(canvas);
      //  }



    }

    /**
     * If there is svg , the user called setFillAfter(true) and the progress is finished.
     *
     * @param canvas Draw to this canvas.
     */
    private void fillAfter(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (svgResourceId != 0 && fillAfter && progress == 1f) {
            svgUtils.drawSvgAfter(canvas, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        if (mLoader != null) {
            try {
                mLoader.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unexpected error", e);
            }
        }
        if (svgResourceId != 0) {
            mLoader = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    svgUtils.load(getContext(), svgResourceId);

                    synchronized (mSvgLock) {
                        width = w - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
                        height = h - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
                        paths = svgUtils.getPathsForViewport(width, height);
                        updatePathsPhaseLocked();
                    }
                }
            }, "SVG Loader");
            mLoader.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (svgResourceId != 0) {
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
            return;
        }

        int desiredWidth = 0;
        int desiredHeight = 0;
        final float strokeWidth = paint.getStrokeWidth() / 2;
        for (SvgUtils.SvgPath path : paths) {
            desiredWidth += path.bounds.left + path.bounds.width() + strokeWidth;
            desiredHeight += path.bounds.top + path.bounds.height() + strokeWidth;
        }
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

        int measuredWidth, measuredHeight;

        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            measuredWidth = desiredWidth;
        } else {
            measuredWidth = widthSize;
        }

        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            measuredHeight = desiredHeight;
        } else {
            measuredHeight = heightSize;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }

    /**
     * If the real svg need to be drawn after the path animation.
     *
     * @param fillAfter - boolean if the view needs to be filled after path animation.
     */
    public void setFillAfter(final boolean fillAfter) {
        this.fillAfter = fillAfter;
    }

    /**
     * If you want to use the colors from the svg.
     */
    public void useNaturalColors() {
        naturalColors = true;
    }

    /**
     * Animator for the paths of the view.
     *
     * @return The AnimatorBuilder to build the animation.
     */
    public AnimatorBuilder getPathAnimator() {
        if (animatorBuilder == null) {
            animatorBuilder = new AnimatorBuilder(this);
        }
        return animatorBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Get the path color.
     *
     * @return The color of the paint.
     */
    public int getPathColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

    /**
     * Set the path color.
     *
     * @param color -The color to set to the paint.
     */
    public void setPathColor(final int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path width.
     *
     * @return The width of the paint.
     */
    public float getPathWidth() {
        return paint.getStrokeWidth();
    }

    /**
     * Set the path width.
     *
     * @param width - The width of the path.
     */
    public void setPathWidth(final float width) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    }

    /**
     * Get the svg resource id.
     *
     * @return The svg raw resource id.
     */
    public int getSvgResource() {
        return svgResourceId;
    }

    /**
     * Set the svg resource id.
     *
     * @param svgResource - The resource id of the raw svg.
     */
    public void setSvgResource(int svgResource) {
        svgResourceId = svgResource;
    }

    /**
     * Object for building the animation of the path of this view.
     */
    public static class AnimatorBuilder {
        /**
         * Duration of the animation.
         */
        private int duration = 350;
        /**
         * Interpolator for the time of the animation.
         */
        private Interpolator interpolator;
        /**
         * The delay before the animation.
         */
        private int delay = 0;
        /**
         * ObjectAnimator that constructs the animation.
         */
        private final ObjectAnimator anim;
        /**
         * Listener called before the animation.
         */
        private ListenerStart listenerStart;
        /**
         * Listener after the animation.
         */
        private ListenerEnd animationEnd;
        /**
         * Animation listener.
         */
        private PathViewAnimatorListener pathViewAnimatorListener;

        /**
         * Default constructor.
         *
         * @param pathView The view that must be animated.
         */
        public AnimatorBuilder(final PathView pathView) {
            anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pathView, "percentage", 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        /**
         * Set the duration of the animation.
         *
         * @param duration - The duration of the animation.
         * @return AnimatorBuilder.
         */
        public AnimatorBuilder duration(final int duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the Interpolator.
         *
         * @param interpolator - Interpolator.
         * @return AnimatorBuilder.
         */
        public AnimatorBuilder interpolator(final Interpolator interpolator) {
            this.interpolator = interpolator;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * The delay before the animation.
         *
         * @param delay - int the delay
         * @return AnimatorBuilder.
         */
        public AnimatorBuilder delay(final int delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set a listener before the start of the animation.
         *
         * @param listenerStart an interface called before the animation
         * @return AnimatorBuilder.
         */
        public AnimatorBuilder listenerStart(final ListenerStart listenerStart) {
            this.listenerStart = listenerStart;
            if (pathViewAnimatorListener == null) {
                pathViewAnimatorListener = new PathViewAnimatorListener();
                anim.addListener(pathViewAnimatorListener);
            }
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set a listener after of the animation.
         *
         * @param animationEnd an interface called after the animation
         * @return AnimatorBuilder.
         */
        public AnimatorBuilder listenerEnd(final ListenerEnd animationEnd) {
            this.animationEnd = animationEnd;
            if (pathViewAnimatorListener == null) {
                pathViewAnimatorListener = new PathViewAnimatorListener();
                anim.addListener(pathViewAnimatorListener);
            }
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Starts the animation.
         */
        public void start() {
            anim.setDuration(duration);
            anim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
            anim.setStartDelay(delay);
            anim.start();
        }

        /**
         * Animation listener to be able to provide callbacks for the caller.
         */
        private class PathViewAnimatorListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                if (listenerStart != null) listenerStart.onAnimationStart();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (animationEnd != null) animationEnd.onAnimationEnd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        }

        /**
         * Called when the animation start.
         */
        public interface ListenerStart {
            /**
             * Called when the path animation start.
             */
            void onAnimationStart();
        }

        /**
         * Called when the animation end.
         */
        public interface ListenerEnd {
            /**
             * Called when the path animation end.
             */
            void onAnimationEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

My MainActivity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Demo");
        final PathView pathView = (PathView) findViewById(R.id.pathView);
        final Path path = makeConvexArrow(50, 100);



      /*  switch (count){
            case 1:  pathView.setSvgResource(R.raw.let1); count++; break;
            case 2:  pathView.setSvgResource(R.raw.let2); count++; break;
            case 3:  pathView.setSvgResource(R.raw.let3); count++; break;
            case 4:  pathView.setSvgResource(R.raw.let4); count++; break;
        }*/


        pathView.setPath(path);

        pathView.setFillAfter(true);
        pathView.useNaturalColors();
        pathView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pathView.getPathAnimator().
                        delay(100).
                        duration(60000).
                        interpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).
                        start();
            }
        });
    }

    private Path makeConvexArrow(float length, float height) {
        final Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0.0f, 0.0f);
        path.lineTo(length / 4f, 0.0f);
        path.lineTo(length, height / 2.0f);
        path.lineTo(length / 4f, height);
        path.lineTo(0.0f, height);
        path.lineTo(length * 3f / 4f, height / 2f);
        path.lineTo(0.0f, 0.0f);
        path.close();
        return path;
    }


}
```

Layout xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.sadhana.myapplicationsdvg.PathView
        android:background="#ff07bcd4"
        android:id="@+id/pathView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        app:svg="@raw/l1"
        app:pathColor="@android:color/white"
        app:pathWidth="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the above code I am able to get all the paths from the svg file.
But all the paths start drawing at the same time.

I want a delay.

For example :

After Path1, delay of 5 seconds and then path2 should begin.

Lib used is:

compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'

I am a new to android.Please help me understand how to accomplish the above task.